# Rename a file in JavaScript Node-RED Function Node

Tags: javascript, python, function, node-red

I have this code in my Python3 Function Node

```
os.rename('cont.json', '%s.json'% formated_string)
msg['payload']='%s.json'% formated_string
return msg
```

It renames the file cont.json as formated_string.json (formated_string is the current date). Then it returns the name of the newly renamed file.

I need to do this in the JavaScript Function Node but I can't seem to find out how to write the same simple thing in JavaScript. Help?

Comment: You need `var fs = require('fs')`, but to do that you need to install fs as a global in your instance of node-red

Comment: You can not use `require` by default in a Node-RED function node